# Terraform: How to assign data or local values to variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I have created SSM parameters with

```
variable "s3_ap_arn_name" {
  description = "Name of the s3 access point"
  type        = string
  default     = "s3_ap_arn"
}


variable "central_logging_account_no" {
  description = "central logging account number"
  type        = string
  default     = "123456789"
}

data "aws_iam_account_alias" "current" {}

resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "s3_ap_params" {
  name  = var.s3_ap_arn_name
  type  = "String"
  overwrite = true
  value = "arn:aws:s3:${var.region}:${var.central_logging_account_no}:accesspoint/logging-${data.aws_iam_account_alias.current.account_alias}"
}


data "aws_ssm_parameter" "s3_ap_params" {
  name = var.s3_ap_arn_name
  depends_on = [aws_ssm_parameter.s3_ap_params]
}


locals {
  s3_ap_arn = data.aws_ssm_parameter.s3_ap_params.value
}
```

Now i have a variable defined in the **terraform.dev.tfvars** file and i need to pass **data.aws_ssm_parameter.s3_ap_params.value** or **local.s3_ap_arn** to **s3_acceess_arn =**

```
**terraform.dev.tfvars**

s3_acceess_arn = ?
```

Can anyone help me to pass the data output to variable file. any responses would be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone help me to pass the data output to variable file.

It's **not possible** from TF only. You would have to develop some kind of wrapper, or CI/CD pipeline, around TF which would execute apply one TF scripts, get its outputs, and modify the `tfvars` files for subsequent execution.